# Fetch size in PGConnection.getNotifications

Tags: postgresql, akka, scalikejdbc

A function in my postgresql database sends a notification when a table is updated.
I'm polling that postgresql database by scalikejdbc, to get all the notifications, and then, do something with them.
The process is explained [here](http://www.smartjava.org/content/listen-notifications-postgresql-scala) . A typical reactive system to sql tables updates.
I get the PGConnection from the java.sql.Connection. And, after that, I get the notifications in this way:

```
val notifications = Option(pgConnection.getNotifications).getOrElse(Array[PGNotification]())
```

I'm trying to get the notifications in chunks of 1000 by setting the fetch size to 1000, and disabling the auto commit. But fetch size property is ignored.

Any ideas how I could do that?
I wouldn't want to handle hundreds of thousands of notifications in a single map over my notifications dataset.

pgConnection.getNotifications.size could be huge, and therefore, this code wouldn't scale well.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe use akka-streams and `.group`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better scale, consider using [postgresql-async](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async#listennotify-support-postgresql-only) and [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/index.html): the former is a library that can obtain PostgreSQL notifications asynchronously, and the former is a [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) implementation that provides backpressure (which would obviate the need for paging). For example:

```scala
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

import com.github.mauricio.async.db.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnection
import com.github.mauricio.async.db.postgresql.util.URLParser

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

class DbActor(implicit materializer: ActorMaterializer) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  private implicit val ec = context.system.dispatcher

  val queue =  
    Source.queue[String](Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      .to(Sink.foreach(println))
      .run()

  val configuration = URLParser.parse("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5233/my_db?user=dbuser&password=pwd")
  val connection = new PostgreSQLConnection(configuration)
  Await.result(connection.connect, 5 seconds)

  connection.sendQuery("LISTEN my_channel")
  connection.registerNotifyListener { message =>
    val msg = message.payload
    log.debug("Sending the payload: {}", msg)
    self ! msg
  }

  def receive = {
    case payload: String =>
      queue.offer(payload).pipeTo(self)
    case QueueOfferResult.Dropped =>
      log.warning("Dropped a message.")
    case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued =>
      log.debug("Enqueued a message.")
    case QueueOfferResult.Failure(t) =>
      log.error("Stream failed: {}", t.getMessage)
    case QueueOfferResult.QueueClosed =>
      log.debug("Stream closed.")
  }
}
```

The code above simply prints notifications from PostgreSQL as they occur; you can replace the `Sink.foreach(println)` with another `Sink`. To run it:

```scala
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object Example extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  system.actorOf(Props(classOf[DbActor], materializer))
}
```